# Rewrite Rule Loop. How to stop applying rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file redirecting blog post urls like /blog/2012/11/30/this-post to /blog/post.php?id=this-post.  Works fine until I apply a second rule below it that is also a match.   This rule is set to take a path formatted url like /this/is/a/pageid and redirect to /page.php?id=pageid.  It doesn't care how long the path is, it just uses the last directory in the path as the id.  Unfortunately, this rule matches everything and I'm not sure how to stop the redirect after the first match.  Here is my .htacess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /blog/post.php?id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Putting the rewriteconditions in front of each rewrite seemed to solve my issue.  I'm not exactly sure why though.
 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional query parameter after you redirect the first time and combine that with a simple rewrite condition on the query string to check if that parameter exists or no, try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /blog/post.php?id=$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?r=0(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?id=$1&r=0 [L]
```

Comment: That didn't work for some reason.  Is there a way to say don't process the page.php rule if the directory contains /blog ?